# Discord bot that replies to any message a specific user writes

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I want to make a bot, this is my first one, just to mess with a buddy of mine. Essentially I want it to reply with a random message ANY time he writes in chat.

I have seen a lot used for banning and have found some that could work but I cannot seem to figure out how to have it work for anytime they press enter no matter the words in it.

This seems to be the closest I have found:

```js
const userID = '4608164XXX93150209';

bot.on('message', function(message) {
 if (!message.sender === userID) {
  if (message.content === 'psst') {
   message.channel.send('Hello there!');
  }
 }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Just to be clear I want them to say anything in chat at all, no prefix needed, and have the bot reply with something random from a predefined list but ONLY for that one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `discord.js`, which it looks like you are, you'll need to use the `message.author` property.

```js
const specificUsers = ['ID Here', 'ID #2', 'ID #3', 'etc.']; // list of ids to detect
const messages = ['Message 1', 'Message 2', 'Message 3']; // list of messages to pick random from

// message event
bot.on('message', (message) => {
 // if the author's id matches one of the blacklisted ids
 if (specificUsers.includes(message.author.id))
  // send random message from array
  return message.channel.send(
   messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)]
  );
});
```

```js
const specificUsers = ['123456789', '987654321']; // list of ids to detect
const messages = ['hello', 'goodbye']; // list of messages to pick random from

// example message event
const message = {
  content: 'hello',
  author: {
    id: '123456789'
  }
}

// if the author's id matches one of the blacklisted ids
if (specificUsers.includes(message.author.id))
  // send random message from array
  console.log(messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)]);
```

Comment: Adding <@USERNAME> didnt work... lol I added the #at the end but I want it to be their nickname on the server.

Comment: It should be `<@UserID>`, not `<@Username>`

Answer (score 0):

whatever I understood from you question, below code is more readable:

```js
const blocked_users = ['4608164XXX93150209']; //you may have one more friend like him

bot.on('message', function(message) {
 if (blocked_users.indexOf(message.sender) === -1) {
  if (message.content === 'psst') {
   message.channel.send('Hello there!');
  }
 } else {
  message.channel.send('Get Away from this channel!');
 }
});
```

Comment: My questions is why blocked users? I do not want them to leave. Essentially I want them to say anything in chat at all, no prefix needed, and have the bot reply with something random from a predefined list but ONLY for that one user.

Comment: Not necessarily blocked users. My intention was to specify target_users. Also, perhaps I missed random message generation part from your question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code I used to generate random messages from an input string. It relies on a text file textcorpus.txt in the same directory to work. YOu can fill up this file with short stories from the internet.

Use the run function as an example to generate a random conversation. Since this is typescript and you probably want javascript just remove all the parts, your javascript linter is not happy about and it should work.

```js
run();
async function run() {
 console.log(`START CONVERSATION, LENGTH: ${100} CHUNKS`);
 let conversationLength = 100;
 function togglePartner(partner: string) {
  if (partner == 'Anton') return 'Bella';
  if (partner == 'Bella') return 'Anton';
  else return 'Anton';
 }

 const sendMessage = console.log;

 let i = 0;
 let lastMessage = '';
 let partner = 'Anton';
 while (i < conversationLength) {
  let res = await getResponse(lastMessage);

  res.forEach((sen) => {
   sendMessage(`${partner}: ${sen}`);
   lastMessage = sen;
  });

  partner = togglePartner(partner);
  i++;
 }
}

function roll(zto: number) {
 return Math.random() < zto;
}

export function randomBetween(x: number, y: number) {
 return x + Math.floor(Math.random() * (y - x));
}

export function randomChoice(choices: Array<any>) {
 var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
 return choices[index];
}

export async function getResponse(input: string): Promise<Array<string>> {
 // only affirmation + dryup:

 let finalArray = [];
 if (input[input.length - 1] == '?') finalArray.push(affirmation());
 else if (roll(0.4)) {
  // frage zurück stellen.
  finalArray.push(question(input));
 } else {
  let file = await promises.readFile('./textcorpus.txt');
  let corpus = file.toString();
  let areaIndexStart = randomBetween(0, corpus.length - 300);
  let area = corpus.substring(areaIndexStart, areaIndexStart + 300);
  area = area.replace(/[\s]/g, ' ');
  area = area.replace(/["']/g, '');
  let sentences = area.split(/[.!?]/).map((s) => s.trim());
  sentences.pop();
  sentences.shift();
  if (sentences.length < 1) {
   finalArray.push(affirmation());
  } else {
   // determine count of sentences to return:

   let senNum = randomBetween(1, Math.min(sentences.length, 5));

   for (let i = 0; i < senNum; i++) {
    if (sentences[i].length > 1000) {
     // split sentence up and add as multiple:
     sentences[i]
      .split(',')
      .map((p) => p.trim())
      .forEach((p) => finalArray.push(p));
    } else {
     finalArray.push(sentences[i]);
    }
   }

   /*
      if (roll(0.1)) finalArray.push(affirmation());
      */
  }
 }
 finalArray = finalArray.map((e, i) =>
  e[e.length - 1] != '?' && i == finalArray.length - 1
   ? addEndSign(e.trim())
   : e
 );

 return finalArray;
}

function addEndSign(input: string) {
 return (
  input +
  randomChoice([
   '!!',
   '.',
   '!',
   '?',
   '.',
   '.',
   '!?',
   '??',
   '...',
   '.',
   '.',
   '.',
   '.',
  ])
 );
}

function question(input: string) {
 if (roll(0.65) && input.length > 10) {
  let numberOfWordsForQuestion = randomBetween(1, 5);
  return (
   input
    .split(/[.!?\s]/)
    .filter((e, i) => i < numberOfWordsForQuestion)
    .join(' ') + '?'
  );
 } else {
  // question related to input
  // generic question
  return affirmation();
 }
}

function affirmation() {
 return randomChoice([
  'yeah',
  'yea',
  'no',
  'just kidding',
  'not really',
  'yes wtf',
  'youre right',
  'no, actually not',
  'no',
  'naah',
  'yessir',
  'hahaha yes',
  'absolutely',
  'nah',
  'uhm yes',
  'I think so',
  "surprising, isn't it?",
  "You don't think so?",
  'omg, really?',
  'really?',
  'Thats not good',
  'I like that',
  'hmmm',
  'weird flex bro',
  'This is not true',
  'you sure?',
  'Why?',
  'No way!',
  'Why that?',
  'where though?',
  'so what?',
  'sure?',
  'wtf?',
  'Hav you seen that?',
  'right now?',
  'what do you think?',
  'wdym?',
  'lol',
  'almost certainly',
  'no way!?',
  'me bored, can you change the topic?',
  'okay',
  'lets talk about something else',
  'Can you say that again?',
  'Wait what?',
  'eehm what?',
  'interesting',
  'cant believe that',
  'yeah yeah yeah',
  'ehem',
  'uhmm what?',
  'not really',
  '',
 ]);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will have to look over that, which will take some time as I am brand new. Just to be clear I want them to say anything in chat at all, no prefix needed, and have the bot reply with something random from a predefined list but ONLY for that one user. This should do that?

Comment: Ah okay. No this just generates a naturally appearing message from a huge chunk of text. I used that to send 1000 messages from instagram bots to each other. It has actuaslly nothing to do with discord.